What's the difference between requesting and waiting when calling someone with Telegram?
When I call someone using the Telegram application, before the call get connected I see requesting, waiting and ringing. I understand that ringing means that the recipient's phone is ringing. But what's the difference between requesting and waiting?

Reddit user FactoryOfShit answered:


Requesting = asking Telegram's servers to start a call
Waiting = waiting for the recipient's telegram client to receive the call request and confirm that the ringing has started
Ringing = obviously waiting for the user to pick up



For such apps waiting involves the recipient choosing the app, it may be on the web version or on the phone
